# Prove that when $f = g - h$ and $g, h$ are measurable nonnegative functions then $f^{+} \leq g$ and $f^{-} \leq h$

Tags: measure-theory, functions, inequality

Prove that when $f = g - h$ and $g, h$ are measurable nonnegative functions then $f^{+} \leq g$ and $f^{-} \leq h$.

Since
$$
f = f^{+} - f^{-} = (g-h)^{+} - (g-h)^{-}
$$
then
$$
f^{+} = (g-h)^{+} \leq g^{+} = g
$$
Is that correct?

How can I prove that $f^- \leq h$? I tried
$$
f^- = (g-h)^- \leq g^- -h^- = 0 + h^+ = h^+ = h
$$
but it does not seem right as $-h^- \neq (-h)^- = h^+$ and I pretty much assumed the contrary ($-h^- = (-h)^-$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
f^{+} = (g-h)^{+} \leq g^{+} = g
$$
is correct. For the other estimate you can use that $f^{-} = (-f)^{+}$:
$$
f^{-} = (-f)^{+} = (h-g)^{+} \leq h^{+} = h \, .
$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$h=g-f=g-f^++f^-\geq f^-$$

since you have already proved that $g\geq f^+$.